# Passing a varchar type parameter and using it in set @SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that has this line:

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT path,title,tags
            FROM (
                  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY file_number) AS Row, *
                  FROM  files) AS tbl 
            WHERE file_number IN (SELECT tag_file_number 
                                  FROM tags 
                                  WHERE tag LIKE ' + @Conditions + '), Row >= '
                   + CONVERT(varchar(9), @StartIdx) + ' AND
                   Row <= ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @EndIdx)
```

I get an error when I pass 'bus' as a parameter value. My objective is to pass a piece of SQL query and substitute it in the place of `@conditions`.

I may also pass '%bu% or tag Like %time% or tag Like %bus time%' I think this is not hard to do but I simply can't figure it out. It's a very specific problem, therefore I can't even google it up. Please help me. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Missing quotes in your query after the like statement. Should be like ''' + @Conditions + ''')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are missing the quotes**, try it like this:

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT path,title,tags
        FROM (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY file_number) AS Row, *
              FROM  files ) AS tbl WHERE file_number in(select tag_file_number from tags where tag like "' + @Conditions + '"), Row >= '
                            + CONVERT(varchar(9), @StartIdx) + ' AND
               Row <=  ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @EndIdx)
```

Now what's happening is `where tag like bus` and it must be `where tag like "bus"`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working for me now. Basically, I didn't know how to use nested quotation marks. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It says vote up requires 15 reputation. I am sorry but I will when possible.